# Relation between KMP algorithm and Z algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, search

`KMP` and `Z` algorithms are well known algorithms for string searching,

`KMP` algorithm deals with finding the patterns through a KMP failure function which is defined as (`pat` being the searching pattern)

> lps[i] = the longest proper prefix of pat[0..i] which is also a suffix of pat[0..i].

e.g for `string "abcab"` it would be `[0, 0, 0, 1, 2]`

where as `Z` algorithm uses the z function which is defined as:

> Given a string S of length n, the Z Algorithm produces an array Z where Z[i] is the length of the longest substring starting from pat[i] which is also a prefix of pat.

Now the question is can we achieve the `Z` function by the use of `KMP` algorithm?
What I am searching for is some modifications in the `lps` array that leads to the same results as the `Z[i]` array.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: algorithm is wrong**

```
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    if lps[i] != 0:
        Z[i - lps[i] + 1] = lps[i]
```

After that in `Z[i]` will be the maximum length of the suffix, that starts in position `i` and which is also a prefix of the string.

**EDIT**

As nikhil_vyas noted, the proposed algorithm does not solve your problem. What it actually does is partially filling `Z` array with the longest suffixes and some others. Such incomplete array can basically help you to solve several "find the longest something in the string" problems, but it does not answer your question.

The easiest way to rebuild `Z` array having `lps` array that comes to my mind is to build the string, corresponding to the `lps` array and then build `Z` array for that string. But I am not sure whether it suits your definition of "some modifications in the `lps` array".

Comment: Why is it necessary that this will fill the Z array for all indexes?

Comment: Hey @Mikhail, thought you might want to check over my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it.

```py
def Z(lps):
    # First assume that we always need to restart when we find a mismatch.
    Z = [0] * len(lps)

    # Step through adjacent pairs.
    itr = enumerate(zip(lps, lps[1:]), start=1)
    for i, (prev, cur) in itr:
        if cur <= prev: # suffix stopped growing
            Z[i - prev] = prev # Mark this suffix at its beginning.

    # Ending the string is also a way to stop growing the suffix.
    if cur > 0: # if we were still growing a suffix
        # At end of loop, cur is the new prev, and i+1 is the new i.
        # (i == len(lps) - 1, cur == lps[-1])
        Z[i+1 - cur] = cur

    return Z
```

Samples:

```
Z([0,0,0,1,2]) #=> [0,0,0,2,0]
Z([0,0,1,2,1,2]) #=> [0,0,2,0,2,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mikhail Melnik's solution may not compute Z for all indexes in a string like "aaaaa" we need an additional iteration to fill the indexes which are left empty in the first iteration.

```
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    Z[i - lps[i] + 1] = lps[i]
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    Z[i] = max(Z[i], Z[i - 1] - 1)                     `
```

Comment: Unfortunately your modification is also wrong. Consider the string "abab" with lps=[0,0,1,2]. Right Z array would be [0,0,2,0], and your algorithm will produce [0,0,2,1].

Comment: Also note that there was a bug in my initial code. If the last element of lps array is 0, you will get "index out of bounds" exception.