# Simple string compression: removing consecutive repeating substrings

Tags: string, algorithm

I was asked this question recently in an Amazon interview .

Given a string, remove consecutive repeating substrings from it. If there are multiple consecutive intersecting substrings, remove the largest of those.

To make it clear, here are some examples:

- input: `aabcccddeaaa`
  output: `abcdea`   (Compressing the consecutive repeated characters)
- input: `abababcdeee`
  output: `abcde` (Compressing consecutive repeated substrings)
- input: `ababcdabcd`
  output: `ababcd`

(You can compress '`ab`' or '`abcd`', but as length of '`abcd`' is larger you prefer compressing the larger one.)

I could not come up with an efficient implementation, anyone knows a good approach to this?

As this was an interview question, please refrain from using complicated library functions.

Comment: Definitely not regex

Comment: I believe that this is an excellent question. I don't understand why anyone thinks that it should close as "too broad".

Comment: Shouldn't the last example return "abcd" ? "ababcdabcd" => "abcdabcd" =>"abcd". If not, there are cases where the output will not be unique.

Comment: For example: "abcdabcdefgdefg" => "abcdefgdefg" or "abcdabcdefg". If you plan to continue and finish it off, you get a unique output: "abcdefg". My solution does just that.

Comment: @user1952500 The compression process needs to be run on the string only once , not recursively until it is not reducible. So, "ababcdabcd" will reduce to "ababcd" and stop . And yes, as you pointed out for "abcdabcdefgdefg" => "abcdefgdefg" or "abcdabcdefg" , the output may not be unique . I did not clarify this with the interviewer so it is safe to assume to return any of the possible strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without regex... This recursive method works:

```js
var cases = ['aabcccddeaaa', 'abababcdeee', 'ababcdabcd'];

function compress(str) {
  var len, sub, i, n;

  // if str is shorter than 2, can't be any repeating substrings
  if(str.length < 2)
    return str;

  // max meaningful length is str.length/2 (truncated to integer)
  for(len = (str.length / 2) | 0; len > 0; len--) {
    // search for a repeating substring of "len" length starting at index i
    for(i = 0; i + (len * 2) <= str.length; i++) {
      sub = str.substr(i, len);
      // if such a substring exists...
      if(str.indexOf(sub, i + len) == i + len) {
        // "count" how many occurences (advance index till beyond repeats)
        for(n = i + len * 2; str.indexOf(sub, n) == n; n += len);
        // return a string composed of the compressed part before the match +
        // the substring + the compressed part beyond the match
        return compress(str.substr(0, i)) + sub + compress(str.substr(n));
      }
    }
  }

  // if nothing found, return original string
  return str;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(cases.map(compress)));
```

After the long debate in the comments regarding the complexity of the algorithm, I decided to refactor a bit and use a self implemented `startsWith` function, and utilize that to count inner operations (complexity...).

I took the chance to further optimize by minimizing string allocations to a minimum so now the recursion works with the entire string + start/end indexes.

The code below generates an output that includes the input string, result, n^2 (for O(n^2) comparison) and actual inner operation count. I added a few edge cases to show how it performs. I couldn't find an input that results in n^2 count, they were all below.

```js
var cases = ['aabcccddeaaa', 'abababcdeee', 'ababcdabcd',
             'aabaaabaab', '1', '111222', '123456789', '1234567899'];

var innerCount;

function startsWith(str, start, subStart, subLen) {
  var subEnd = subStart + subLen - 1;
  while(subStart <= subEnd) {
    innerCount++;
    if(str[start++] != str[subStart++])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function doCompress(str, maxLen, minIndex, maxIndex) {
  var len, sub, i, n;

  // if str is shorter than 2, can't be any repeating substrings
  if(maxIndex - minIndex + 1 < 2)
    return str.substring(minIndex, maxIndex + 1);

  for(len = maxLen; len > 0; len--) {
    // search for a repeating substring of "len" length starting at index i
    for(i = minIndex; i + (len * 2) <= maxIndex + 1; i++) {
      // if such a substring exists...
      if(startsWith(str, i + len, i, len)) {
        // "count" how many occurences (advance index till beyond repeats)
        for(n = i + len * 2; (n + len <= maxIndex + 1) && startsWith(str, n, i, len); n += len);
        // return a string composed of the compressed part before the match +
        // the substring + the compressed part beyond the match
        return (i > minIndex ? doCompress(str, len - 1, minIndex, i - 1) : '') +
          str.substr(i, len) +
          (n < maxIndex ? doCompress(str, len, n, maxIndex) : '');
      }
    }
  }

  // if nothing found, return original string
  return str.substring(minIndex, maxIndex + 1);
}

function compress(str) {
  innerCount = 0;
  // max meaningful length is str.length/2 (truncated to integer)
  return {
    source: str,
    result: doCompress(str, (str.length / 2) | 0, 0, str.length - 1),
    'n^2': str.length*str.length,
    innerCount: innerCount};
}

alert(JSON.stringify(cases.map(compress), null, '\t'));
```

This solution has a time complexity of O(n^2).

Comment: I doubt this is O(n²). Isn't aready a the first call (with no recursion) O(n²)?

Comment: The recursive calls operate on a different "space" (only a substring of previous string, with a shorter match length), so the recursion doesn't add more complexity

Comment: Mmmh. Following that argumentation, quicksort would be O(n), no?

Comment: It will be O(n^3). The substring is a fraction of the original string and will add to the complexity. Unless the substring is a fixed fraction, it may not even be logarithmic and will lead to O(n^3).

Comment: @undur_gongor quicksort operates on the same space every time (the items below & above the current item). (and user1952500..) My algo doesn't. the complexity is length of match (in the range of string.length / 2 -> 1) * starting index (0 -> string.length - 1). The recursion doesn't repeat any iteration already done in a previous iteration

Comment: I don't know much about js. Could you mention the complexity of: "sub = str.substr(i, len);" and "str.indexOf(sub, i + len)"

Comment: @user1952500 - You've got a good point there... I overlooked the internal complexity of these functions and concentrated on the logic of the algorithm with the (wrong) assumptions that there are irrelevant. Anyway, `indexOf` can be substituted for a more optimal function (could use `startsWith` in ES6) and with a longer, more verbose implementation `substr` can be replaced by calling `compress` with a pair of indices (start, end). So basically, I still think it's O(n^2).

Comment: Actually I doubt that the recursive part can be optimized out to a constant as well. Suppose the outer loop is O(n) and the next loop is O(n - k). Do you mean to say that the inner loop is O(k) ?

Comment: Also, startsWith is not constant time and is linear (or more).

Comment: @user1952500 I'm not saying the inner loop is O(k), I'm saying O(n) * O(n - k) is O(n^2), not O(n^3)

Comment: Yes, I want to know why you treat the innermost recursive function as O(1).

Comment: Actually there is no point discussing this until there is a clear demonstration that it is O(n^2). It is not the case as per current code with so many high-level functions being called (which was against the OP requirements) and I doubt there can be an algo that beats the Z-algo demonstrated in gusfield's book and referenced by Pham here.

Comment: @user1952500 I'm not. I'm saying that a recursive implementation doesn't automatically mean increased complexity (for example, f(arr){ return new Array(arr[0] + 1, f(arr[1..n]))} is recursive but is O(n)). In my case, that's a valid claim. Regarding `startsWith`, as I noted before, valid point and I need to see if that can be optimized as well. But regardless of anything else, this is the only answer (so far) that work, so why the downvotes?

Comment: @user1952500 and the comment about "high-level functions" is completely out of place. a substring is a basic feature available in practically any standard library / native modern language and is easy to implement. That's redundant verbosity.

Comment: @Amit, I did not downvote you. When I interview and I see a candidate using something like indexOf in a function where finding the substring is key, I would ask the candidate to implement it. Such functions hide complexity quite a bit. There are many ways of implementing indexOf and the naive implementation can be quadratic (O(m*n)) unless the candidate uses something specific like KMP or Boyer-Moore (or knows how JS implements it internally and mentions the compexity).

Comment: @user1952500 as I said, indexOf is used for brevity, not performance. A simple straigthforward startsWith (O(n)) would be a much better alternative. BUT - I still "feel" (although further research is required to prove that) that even with startsWith "logic", the algorithm is O(n^2) due to the combination of possible outcomes (for example, if startsWith is true, the entire substring is left out of further processing, if it's false, only [1:N] elements were processed since sub is N/2 at most)

Comment: Well it's your perspective. It does matter to me but my comment should not matter to the OP. I am only interested in the O(n^2) since that is independent of perspectives. I think there should be an explanation around it rather than misleading the others who may look at the solution superficially.

Comment: Can this algorithm handle the case `aabaaabaab -> aabaab -> aab`? I think as you `return compress(str.substr(0, i)) + sub + compress(str.substr(n));` , it will fail on this test case.

Comment: @PhamTrung - `aabaaabaab -> aabaaab`. (the repeat is `[aaba][aabaab]` an that turns to `aabaaab`)

Comment: @Amit I tried to run your code snippet and the result is `aabaab` , which can be further reduced to `aab`

Comment: @Amit , reread the question , I think further reduction is not necessary (last example), so your algo is correct :)

Comment: @undur_gongor, user1952500, Pham, all... See the revised answer, with the complexity profiling version. O(n^2)!

Comment: How ? startsWith is linear. And it is used in an if statement and also in a loop within two nested loops.

Comment: @user1952500 - Did you look at the output? it shows you can't get to a n^2 complexity (at least not in all samples I tried, please feel free to prove otherwise). I'd love to try and explain this further but I can't really do much more than what I already did and say that due to the combination of branching and "dissecting the problem space", it maintains O(n^2) (or in fact lower than that, which I'm still thinking about but lets leave that aside for now). Care to try and calculate that yourself / find a sample that shows otherwise?

Comment: I hadn't looked at it. Thanks for adding it. It looks like it's about (n/2)^2. Let me check how that it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For a string `X`, we can find the largest consecutive repeating substring in O(n^2) using [Z-algorithm](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2011/cmsc858s/Lec02-zalg.pdf) which `Given a string S of length n, the Z Algorithm produces an array Z where Z[i] is the length of the longest substring starting from pat[i] which is also a prefix of pat` ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521337/relation-between-kmp-algorithm-and-z-algorithm))

For each suffix of `X` start at `i`, applying Z-algorithm for this substring:

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < X.length(); i++)
   int[]z = Z-algo(X.substring(i)); //this take O(n)
   for(int j = i + result + 1; j < X.length(); j++)
       if(z[j] >= j - i + 1)
          result = (j - i + 1);
```

<s>Repeating the above procedure until we cannot find any repeating substring, we can obtain a O(n^3) algorithm.</s>

**Note**: after reread the question, especially the last example, I figure out that valid repeating substrings are only limited from the original's substrings. So, the time complexity can be reduced to O(n^2 log n) by using a max heap.

Answer (score 1):

```
pos=[]
dstr={}
final=[]
x="ababcdabcdcde"

for k in re.finditer(r"(?=(.+?)\1+)",x):        #Find start of all overlapping strings
    pos.append(k.start())
i=0
for k in pos: #Find end of overlapping strings
    s=re.findall(r"^((.*)\2+)",x[k:])
    dstr[i]=(k,len(s[0][0]))
    i=i+1
#print dstr.values()
k=0
while k< len(dstr.values())-1:           #remove smaller length overlapping result
    if dstr.values()[k+1][0]<dstr.values()[k][1]<dstr.values()[k+1][1]:
        pass
    else:
        final.append(dstr.values()[k][0])
    k=k+1
if dstr.values()[k-1][0] in final:
    pass
else:
    final.append(dstr.values()[k][0])
#print final
for k in final:             #remove strings
    s=re.sub(r"(.*)\1+",r"\1",x[k:])
    x=x[:k]+s
print x
```

This is in python.Works fine with given input.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straightforward non-recursive O(n^3). The key observation is this: suppose there is a string 'aabcbcabbc', if we are only to remove *consecutive repetitions*, as long as we reduce strings of length=1 first, length=2 second, and so on, we can reduce it and the reduction will be optimal. Hence

'aabcabbc' => 'abcbcabc' => 'abcabc' => 'abc'

Python code:

```
def strcompress(str):
   strlen = len(str)
   for size in range (1, strlen // 2):
      for i in range (0, strlen - 2 * size + 1):
            str1 = str[i:i+size]
            str2 = str[i+size:i+2*size]
            while str1 == str2:
               str = str[:i+size] + str[i+2*size:]
               strlen = len(str)
               if i + 2*size > strlen:
                  break
               str2 = str[i+size:i+2*size]
   print("The compressed string is:" + str)   
   return
```

Example:

```
>>> strcompress("ababcdabcd")
The compressed string is:abcd
```

**EDIT:** Fixed a few bugs in code. This should work for existing samples and the example I provided.

Comment: That doesn't even work for the sample provided: strcompress(ababcdabcd) != ababcd

Comment: Yes, I fixed this up. Sorry about that, I'm new to python and using SO to write code snippets and learn more about the language. So I get a few bugs now and then.

Comment: No, you didn't fix it, because your approach is fundamentally wrong. When starting with the smallest substring and growing in further iterations you're not giving the algorithm the chance to find the larger substrings before modifying them. you're result is not the required output (read the question again, and my previous comment)

Comment: This is a correct approach. If you consider "ababcdabcd", it can be reduced to "abcdabcd" and then to "abcd". Whether you do this or do {"ababcdabcd"=>"ababcd"=>"abcd"} doesn't matter. Actually reducing from largest to least hurts but the reduction from smallest to largest should work as long as _repetitions are consecutive_. If you think otherwise, please provide a counterexample or help me understand.

Comment: As a proof, suppose we have abcS1S2def where S1==S2. Now if we have S1=S3dddS4, it doesn't matter that I convert S1 to S3dS3 because S2 will also be converted in the same iteration in the same way. When the reduced S1 is considered later, it will be equal to the reduced S2.

Comment: **R-E-A-D   T-H-E   Q-U-E-S-T-I-O-N**. input: `ababcdabcd` output: `ababcd`

Comment: Ah ok, sorry about that. I have added a comment to the question. As it stands now, the output can be non-unique.